# how to extract values from previous dataframe based on row and column condition?

Tags: pandas

sorry for my naive, but i can't solve this. any reference or solution ?

df1 =

```
              date  a   b   c
    0   2011-12-30  100 400 700
    1   2021-01-30  200 500 800
    2   2021-07-30  300 600 900
```

df2 =

```
          date  c   b
0   2021-07-30  NaN NaN
1   2021-01-30  NaN NaN
2   2011-12-30  NaN NaN
```

desired output:

```
          date  c   b
0   2021-07-30  900 600
1   2021-01-30  800 500
2   2011-12-30  700 400
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with convert `date` to indices in both DataFrames:

```
df = df2.set_index('date').fillna(df1.set_index('date')).reset_index()
print (df)
         date      c      b
0  2021-07-30  900.0  600.0
1  2021-01-30  800.0  500.0
2  2011-12-30  700.0  400.0
```

Comment: as always many..many..many.. thanks for the logic jezrael.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, using [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html):

```
df2 = df2.set_index('date')
df2.update(df1.set_index('date'))
df2.reset_index()
```

Output:

```
         date      c      b
0  2021-07-30  900.0  600.0
1  2021-01-30  800.0  500.0
2  2011-12-30  700.0  400.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`reindex_like`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex_like.html) `df2` after setting date a temporary index:

```
out = df1.set_index('date').reindex_like(df2.set_index('date')).reset_index()
```

output:

```
         date    c    b
0  2021-07-30  900  600
1  2021-01-30  800  500
2  2011-12-30  700  400
```

Comment: Hi mozway.. like your answer as well.. thanks for sharing the solution. really helpful

Comment: @stvlam22 you're welcome. Of note `reindex_like` if more efficient than `fillna` if you have a large dataset ;)